# How to avoid Cache error on django 1.11 and redis 3.0

Tags: python, django, redis

Recently our Redis pack was updated from version 2.10.6 to version 3.0.1.

Because of that we start to have a DataError exception, raised when we try to login to Django web site.

The solution we got was to revert the update and fix the Redis version to 2.10.6, this worked fine, and according to the Redis [docs](https://pypi.org/project/redis/), this error is expected, as they changed some encoding restrictions:

> Redis-py 3.0 only accepts user data as bytes, strings or numbers (ints, longs, and floats). Attempting to specify a key or a value as any other type will raise a DataError exception.

My question, is that if this is an error with Django 1.11? And, if this is the case, how can we update to Redis 3.0, without getting that raise?

Comment: Django doesn’t support redis out of the box so this is not a bug in Django. If you are using any other packages like django-redis then include that in your question. For questions like this, please show the full traceback so that we can see the exact error and where it is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django-redis does not support redis-py 3.0 yet. See [this issue](https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis/issues/342) for more information.